# How do I convert a Twitter User ID to a Twitter Username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app in Rails that needs to convert a Twitter ID into the Twitter username. This is the code that pulls the ID.

```
url = 'http://twitter.com/' + params[:username]
buffer = open(url, 'UserAgent' => 'irb').read
@vouched_user_twitter_id = buffer[/\d+(?=\.rss)/]
```

How do I use that number to pull the username once I no longer have params.

Comment: `TwitterUsername twitterUsername = (TwitterUsername) twitterUserId; // couldn't resist`

Comment: How do I turn that into Rails code? Sorry. Ultra noob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup) method.  This corresponds to the [users method](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/twitter/Twitter/Base:users) of [this gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Thanks Matthew - Can you link me to a resource on how to execute that? I'm a noob.

Comment: You just have to make an HTTP GET or POST request (in Javascript this would be an Ajax call) to the given url (`http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml` or `http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json`). Of course, you actually need to provide user IDs or screen names you're interested in, so, to poach from that page, you might request `http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=1401881,1401882` to look up user IDs 1401881 and 1401882 and return the result as XML.

Comment: You have to authenticate first, which is one of the reasons a library is convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can [get the Twitter username from Twitter ID without using the Twitter API](http://metadatascience.com/2013/08/13/how-to-get-twitter-username-from-twitter-id/). Calling Twitter API has two issues:

1. It needs an access token after the release of Twitter API version 1.1.
2. The number of requests is limited to 150 requests per hour.

Comment: does this approach still work?  I couldn't get the code to work.

Comment: This method does no longer work. Twitter replies with: *Hmm...this page doesn’t exist. Try searching for something else.*

Answer (score -1):

You are looking up user id by RSS, that wrong.

You can inspect user's avatar in tweet list dom with firebug and use "data-user-id" param. That is if you need to get id once for testing purposes. Otherwise, yes - use twitter API described above.

Answer (score -1):

Since March 2013 Twitter has changed their REST 1.0 API, now the procedure is different, read more [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Comment: this link is broken